# Replacing string having forward slash in sed

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I wish to replace

```
x.y.z.zz=/a/b/c/d/
```

with

```
x.y.z.zz=/a/b/e/d/
```

i know `x.y.z.zz` in advance.I also know the line number in advance.
I have tried this

```
sed  "11s/.*/x.y.z.zz=\/a\/b\/e\/d\/" filename
```

but this is giving error. Is there a better way to directly search and replace the string ?

Comment: what do you mean by better way to directly search? sed is searching and replacing anyways.

Comment: i already know the key `x.y.z.zz` then can i directly replace value using the key @Pawan

Comment: You can just replace 'c' with 'e' if you know your input will always have "x.y.z.zz=/a/b/c/d" always. e.g. just execute "sed s/c/e/"

Comment: @Pawan not working i did this -- `sed 11s/c/e filename`

Comment: sure why not. you don't need to change the complete line always. You can just change a character or a word in the text.

Comment: s/c/e/ you missed last '/'

Comment: Great, this is working, you can make it an answer. i will surely upvote it (sorry wont accept as i have already accepted one )  ! @Pawan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` replaces by using the `sed 's/pattern/replacement/'` syntax. In your case, you were missing the last `/`. So by saying this it will work:

```
sed '11s/.*/x.y.z.zz=\/a\/b\/e\/d\//' file
                                   ^
```

However, it may be cleaner to use another delimiter, so that the syntax is more clear. What about `#`? (It can also be `~`, `_`, etc.):

```
sed '11s#.*#x.y.z.zz=/a/b/e/d/#' file
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
a
x.y.z.zz=/a/b/c/d/
b
c
```

Let's replace line 2:

```
$ sed '2s#.*#x.y.z.zz=/a/b/e/d/#' a
a
x.y.z.zz=/a/b/e/d/
b
c
```

Comment: 1. why do i need to add extra `/` at the end ?  and 
2. Why is it working when u have added `#` at the place of `/` ?

Comment: Because the syntax is `sed 's/pattern/replacement/'`. Some cases you want to replace multiple times, so you use `g` --> `sed 's/pattern/replacement/g'`. So you see the last slash can precede another option. Regarding **2**, note that in the `#` approach I am using a `#` at the end, so it is exactly the same syntax.

Comment: @shubham tripathi, sed takes any character as delimiter e.g. "sed s/c/e/" is same as "sed s_c_e_" or " sed s#c#e#" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace `c` with `e` if you know your input will always have "x.y.z.zz=/a/b/c/d". 
 e.g. just executing `sed s/c/e/`

will just replace `c` with `e` in the line. Also, you don't need to change the complete line always. You can just change a character or a word in the text.
Additionally, if a line contains more than one occurrence of character/word, this command will only change the first one
 e.g. if input string is `x.y.z.zz=/a/b/c/d/c`, executing `sed s/c/e/` will have output `x.y.z.zz=/a/b/e/d/c`
If all the occurrences need to be changed `g` (global) needs to be added in `sed` command 
e.g. `sed s/c/e/g` will give output `x.y.z.zz=/a/b/e/d/e`
If `sed` needs to be executed only for a particular line, line number shall be mentioned in the `sed` command itself, as done in the question.
 This is the link (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), I always refer when in question with `sed`

Comment: i made it work like this .. `sed 11s/c/e/ filename`. please note that i have added line number `11` to it.