# I want to replace the above line with the line below using sed command for the spring datasource

Tags: python, shell, sed

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/jdbc/ph20guib
```

I want to replace the above line with the line below using sed command

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/comp/env/jdbc/ph20guib
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing string having forward slash in sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565617/replacing-string-having-forward-slash-in-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your properties file is file.txt, the following will work :

```
$ sed -i 's/\/jdbc\/ph20guib/\/comp\/env\/jdbc\/ph20guib/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it easily using sed as

```
sed -i 's|=java.*|=java:/comp/env/jdbc/ph20guib|' <file>
```